# Filesystem resize after Gparted?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, gparted, lvm

I resized a `/dev/sda5` which is a `"[Encrypted] lvm2 pv"` file system. The size is now 91.13G with Unused 28.76G.

However, df -h is not showing this:

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg0--7ee61a-root   54G   47G  3.7G  93% /
```

I think I need to use lvextend, but I this won't work:

```
$ sudo lvextend -L90G /dev/mapper/vg0--7ee61a-root 
  Insufficient free space: 9135 extents needed, but only 7363 available
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `resize2fs` to resize the filesystem to match what you have done with Gparted or lvextend.

Whenever you are doing this you have to imagine that you are making the logical volume larger with Gparted or lvextend, and then you need to resize the file system to make the newly allocated space usable.